# Help with accessing wp-admin page and resolving error messages

Tags: php, wp-admin, errors, login, ftp

I was recently advised to reinstall both wordpress and my wordpress theme due to (i think) a still unresolved error with a slide manager, but on doing so, apppear to have lost access to the admin-wp page login and instead now have a blank page with just the following errors appearing:

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/myusername/public_html/wp-content/themes/Carta/engine/backend.php on line 51

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/myusername/public_html/wp-content/themes/Carta/engine/backend.php on line 65

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/myusername/public_html/wp-content/themes/Carta/engine/backend.php:51) in /home/myusername/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 890

I had also installed a couple of plugins recently, which I thought might be the problem, but on disabling them via FTP this didn't make a difference. If anyone has any suggestions as to what these errors refer to and how I can resolve them, I'd be very grateful. I'm a total novice with all of this, so the more detailed your instructions, the better. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All of errors you quoted refer to theme's folder, so it seems like theme breaks something at admin side. Not enough details to say what causes those errors and from quick Google theme doesn't seem to be free (and so available to check).

I suggest you contact theme's developer, if he does provide support for it.